# How do I ssh into a machine and cat a file on that box simulteanously?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

Basically I want to remotely cat a file, this is what I have so far. It doesn't work. I'm fairly new to all this:

```
echo /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@HOSTNAME "cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: use [`ssh-copy-id`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh-copy-id.1.html) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use `echo`, use `cat`

```
cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@HOSTNAME "cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

- `echo /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` will output the string /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
- `cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` will output the content of /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
- `ssh-copy-id -i my/alternate/pub.key root@HOSTNAME` might be a solution, you will be asked password the first time.

Answer (score 0):

After setting trusts between servers with you can cat a file with ssh command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id username@server.com
ssh -l username server.ip.addr "cat file.txt"
```